# How to convert large Chisel design to C++ model with Verilator?

Tags: riscv, chisel, verilator

I encountered an issue about bad memory allocation while compiling large chisel hardware design to C++ model using verilator backend.

When i want to built a large PE design (36x36 for example), I write my code like this

```scala
 PEArray = Seq.fill(height)(Seq.fill(width)(Module new PE).io)
```

and the verilator would crash then throw

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'  what(): std::bad_alloc
```

Something like the memory not enough cause this problem, is there any memory-efficiency Chisel3 built-in function or other ways to solve this problem?

Comment: There is a discussion about memory on chisel-user mailing list : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chisel-users/mjfFE5C8Sfk

Comment: @FabienM Thanks for your comments. I have already provided the memory size 128GB to sbt compiling and it not working. I think this problem is not caused by Java because Chisel generate the verilog file (*.v) normally, but can't convert this verilog file to C++ model by verilator.

Comment: To make sure I understand, Chisel is generating Verilog but Verilator is crashing when trying to compile it? If so, it might be worth asking the Verilator devs about it. Can you share your source code or Verilog file?

Comment: Echoing Jack, you'll attract more answers if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).